# SQL Redshift Select query to get total sales in desc

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Can some 1 help me with sql redshift query to get the result the way mentioned below

3 columns
order_date ,daily_sale (sale made on tht day), total_sale (total_sale till date)

`order_date  daily_sale      total_sale
2017-01-31  1830             206316.4
2017-01-30  2487.5           206316.4
2017-01-29  5456             206316.4
2017-01-28  2786.2           206316.4
2017-01-27  2337             206316.4
2017-01-26  1404.2           206316.4`

How can get total sale in such a way

`order_date daily_sale       total_sale
2017-01-31  1830             206316.4
2017-01-30  2487.5           204486.4 (206316.4 -1830)
2017-01-29  5456             201999.4 (206316.4 -1830-2487.5) and so on`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your service (DB) supports window functions or not.

If yes, you can try this query:

(put instead of `ttt` your table name)

```
SELECT ttt.order_date, daily_sale, total_sale,  daily_sale+total_sale-t.total_last_daily  AS desirable_column  FROM ttt
INNER JOIN (SELECT order_date, SUM(daily_sale) OVER( ORDER BY order_date desc) total_last_daily FROM ttt) AS t
ON ttt.order_date = t.order_date
ORDER BY ttt.order_date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked 

but we need add  
`( SUM(daily_sale) OVER( ORDER BY order_date desc ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
`

In the inner query otherwise  it would throw an error
`Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause`

But still thnx for solution

Comment: You’re welcome, I never used `amazon-redshift` but my query worked SQL SERVER well. Glad if that helped you